# Hide new window in javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, browser, hide

Is it possible to hide new browser window before opening it. I open the window using

```
var printwindow = window.open('');
```

Comment: question is not very clear, some more information please.

Comment: You cannot hide something that does not yet exist.

Comment: Is it possible to create a popup window instead of new browser tab?